# Client-side Loggly Meteor 1.4.1

Tags: meteor, winston, loggly

I'm trying to setup some kind of logging for my meteor app and chose Loggly, I read [this article](https://www.loggly.com/blog/meteor-logging-quickstart/), but I can't get the client-side implementation to work.

---

```
// in startup/client/loggly-client.js

import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { winston } from 'meteor/clinical:winston-browser-logging';

winston.info("winston-client has started on the client!");
```

---

```
// in startup/client/index.js

import './loggly-client.js';
import './routes.js';
```

---

Error I'm getting is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'info' of undefined`

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/clinical-meteor/winston-browser-logging/blob/master/package.js it should be `Winston`, not `winston`.